# Can I get the property's value as number in a template property decorator in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to get the property's value as number in such decorator. Could it be possible to do this `without` using `any` as target's type?

```
function deco () {
  return function <T, K extends keyof T> (target:T, key:K) {
    /* Error:
Conversion of type 'T[K]' to type 'number' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'T[keyof T]' is not comparable to type 'number'.
    Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not comparable to type 'number'.
      Type 'T[symbol]' is not comparable to type 'number'.ts(2352)
    */
    if (typeof target[key] === 'number') {
      const value = target[key] as number
    }
  }
}

class A {
  @deco()
  static bar:number = 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I would do is to declare the const variable `value` before the if block, and narrow down its type with the if guard instead of the reverse. See below code for `deco`.

Another approach I would take is to add a constraint to the type parameter `T`, that way types of values of `T` are acknowledged by typescript. However, typescript will yell at you if there is no index signature for class A's static members. See below code for `deco1`.

```
function deco () {
    return function (target: any, key: string) {
        const value = target[key];
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
            value
        }
    }
}
function deco1 () {
    return function<T extends Record<string, number>> (target: T, key: string) {
        if (typeof target[key] === 'number') {
            const value = target[key]
        }
    }
}

class A {
    @deco()
    static bar: number = 10;

    @deco1()
    static foo: number = 10;
    // static [P: string]: number; // this fixes the error above

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&install-plugin=typescript-playground-link-shortener#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYTogFASkQbwChETEAnVKEMpUSWBbKAQzIHNKAuRZsATwA0iANao+3AM5QyMMGzxFSSxBjBTEAN2YAbEKkQBeRC3aUA2qL4BdANzFlJGMCZ8ADqjjOtu-Qb+IAcjAQAFsAI1QyAIV7ByVvPVjlAF8k1NS6aHgkNAwARmwYpQoqGkRMhjAAHgAVRFQADyhUMGQJRAAldDgyZCqpGTkhYPDIgD4xplYOKG4aoUtJaVl5AiSlJxd3T2Np80srQ38g0IioorilVXUE313TKAsxK3XSVKV0wkIIbWYJdoAgmslAABXJwXBJKTMWAQRBhVjcEZnQyIPIABjsSTB3TykKU0Nh5TgcCRp0iqIxdiUAHoaYhCTA4WYAApLQZsKxk0ZkGyIOnGAAWMHawBgDVQ7Sggv0kTIPR4YTgGlQX1SQA)

Comment: I got an issue when I add that indexer: `'static' modifier cannot appear on an index signature.ts(1071)`.

Comment: @jayatubi yeah right... you're gonna want to upgrade to TS4.3 for that syntax to work.

Comment: I'm currently using tsc version 4.3.2. What else do I need?

Comment: @jayatubi sounds like the right version to me... can you reproduce this in ts playground?

Comment: The playground link you post was fine but I'm working on a node.js based project so I need to make the tsc work fine too.